# Trouble with loop jquery fadeIn() fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, css, loops, css-position

I'm struggling with making this loop work.

I have two logos both centered on the landing page of a website I'm working on. I tried to code the loop so when one image `fadesOut()` the other one `fadesIn()` but it's not working.

I tried with `setInterval()` but the images start to appear one in top of the other. If I delay one image so it starts the animation when the other finishes something happens with the position of the object and it's displayed non-centered.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function somethingfade() {

    $(".logo1").fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);

    $(".logo2").delay(6500).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".logo1").delay(7000).fadeIn(1000);

  }
  somethingfade();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.logocontainer {
  display: block;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.logo1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="logocontainer">

    <img class="logo1" id="logoChange" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/?text=logo1" alt="logo1">

    <img class="logo2" id="logoChange" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/?text=logo2" alt="logo2">

  </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are asynchronous functions. You need to use callbacks to make the animation look synchronous:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function somethingfade() {
    $(".logo1").fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(".logo2").delay(6500).fadeIn(1000, function() {
          $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(".logo1").delay(7000).fadeIn(1000);
          });
        })
      })
    });
  }

  somethingfade();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.logocontainer {
  display: block;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.logo1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="logocontainer">
    <img class="logo1" id="logoChange" src="_css/_images/UshuaiaLocals_Single.png" alt="logo 1">
    <img class="logo2" id="logoChange" src="_css/_images/UshuaiaLocals_Single_Coord.png" alt="logo 2">
  </div>
</div>
```